# NodeJS SRCDS View log of grandchild process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing an app to handle my server and be able to log all the output to a file. I am just at the stage where I am seeing all of the output first, but it looks like I am not getting output from the child process that my first child process creates. Here is my code:

run.js

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')

const server = spawn('bash', ['srcds_run'])

console.log('spawned ' + server.pid)

server.stdout.on('data', data => {
    process.stdout.write(data)
})

server.stderr.on('data', data => {
    process.stdout.write(data)
})

server.stdin.on('data', data => {
    process.stdout.write(data)
})
```

In the console, it prints everything until the `srcds_run` script passes it on to `srcds_linux` which is the main server process. Once it passes it on, there is no longer any output, but the process is started and the server is up.

Here is an example of how the process tree looks.

https://i.linkjay.io/JBipdX.png

And how it runs in node

https://i.linkjay.io/YzmhIL.png

It will print anything from `srcds_run`, but not `srcds_linux`.

Logaddress is not an option here either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution!

`srcds_run` is a bash script that eventually starts the binary `srcds_linux`.

I found out that I could use [node-pty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pty) to start `srcds_run` which would start `srcds_linux` in that pty. From there, I would have access to the bash process as if it were a child_process. You can manage stdio, and manage the process itself.

Code example:

```
const pty = require('node-pty')
const path = require('path')

const folder = '/home/local/folders/servers/gmod'
const binary = 'srcds_run'

const args = ['-gamemode sandbox', '+map gm_flatgrass']

const proc = pty.spawn('bash', [path.join(folder, binary)].concat(args), {
    cwd: folder
})

proc.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('out: ' + data)
})
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

Comment: Have you had any luck in actually running scrds_linux standalone? I've echo'ed the line in scrds_run which actually calls scrds_linux, but using the exact same command in the terminal gives me an error...